# Font-Family uses different font on same header

Tags: html, css, fonts

When loading a Google font (Open sans) like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and using it in the CSS like this:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important;
```

On different pages but the same header, css etc the page loads:

page 1: font-family: '**Open Sans**',sans-serif !important;

page 2: font-family: 'Open Sans',**sans-serif** !important;

On both pages the Google-font and css get loaded.

Anybody a idea what may cause this?

Comment: Can you show more of your CSS declarations?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: - Could by a cache issue, try clearing that. - do you have an online example for us to look at?

Comment: How have you structured the load? Is the google font loaded before your CSS? Make sure you load your dependencies first!

Comment: Well in the template the fonts are being loaded first, then the custom css where the family rule in in. But because the css gets minified the fonts get loaded after the css. This is the case on both pages, the styles are being set, but on one page it gets the first font family in line, on the other page the second in line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your CSS rule more specific. I see you're using the `!important` tag, so you're probably overwriting existing rules from a framework or elsewhere.

For example, if you're trying to give a font to all headers, you probably have other divs surrounding them. Let's say that div's called `content`:

```
body .content .h1, body .content .h2 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif !important;
}
```

The best thing to do would be the see why your styles aren't being set in inspect element. Right click with Chrome > Inspect over your headers, and see what's styling them. You should try and not use `!important` rules anywhere unless completely necessary.

Comment: Yes i know, that !important was just for testing if it would work that way. The css is for general body{}. The styles are being set, but on one page it gets the first family in line, on the other page the second in line.